# MEMS oscillator how to wire them and can they replace crystals?

Tags: crystal

My question is: Can a MEMS oscillator replace a crystal oscillator?

If answer is yes, how I can wire them to XIN and XOUT? How should I select capacitor? And since they don't have crystal capacitance load, shout or equivalent ESR in their datasheet specifics, how I can choose correct oscillator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a "crystal" replacement it's a "crystal oscillator" replacement. The MEMs replaces the crystal as the reference inside the oscillator circuit.

If you want to use a MEMs oscillator then you don't drive it like you would a crystal, you use it to supply the clock reference to XIN.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MEMS oscillators can replace crystal oscillators. And just as crystal oscillators do they only connect to XIN, as opposed to crystals which are connected to both XIN and XOUT as part of a Pierce oscillator.